# How can two developer with personal Apple Dev accounts work on same code?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I will be working on an iPhone app with another developer. We both have personal accounts. I am the actually owner of the application.

Can we start the same named project and just work of a shared SVN repository with only the classes files being shared? Would this work around any compiling issues?

Thanks

Comment: You want to share compiled code?

Comment: Just compile separate tests. I will distribute and act as the Agent for Ad-hoc distribution etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you don't both start the same project. One of you creates it and imports it to a repository, then both of you check out working copies from the repository.

Comment: So Check in/out the entire project file structure?

Comment: Thanks for the answer as well... super quick :)